# Is it possible to undo a flattr?

Tags: flattr

I just clicked the flattr button on a person's page on Flattr, but I wanted to flattr one of their "things" instead, which I did immediately afterwards. How can I remove/undo the first flattr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You can see as some extra love being sent to that creator.

Comment: :(
Any plans for supporting that in the future? As you might imagine, this behavior is far from ideal!

Comment: If I have understand Flattr correctly, wouldn't it just be possible to give an extra Flattr to all other people you given Flattr to that month? That way, the ratio is the same as if you had given the first one just one Flattr.